# Excel VBA Hex colours not showing correctly

Tags: vba, excel

Please can someone help me before I go a little crazy !

I'm trying to use a scale of colours in VBA and I have the RGB and the Hex values however not all of them output the way I would expect and I think it's to do with the &H prefix

For example

I have a lovely shade of red (RGB 248:105:107 HEX F8696B) that when I'm writing my code I input as :

```
Const Band10Colour As Long = &HF8696B
```

However this is a lovely purple colour

When I look up the the RGB of the purple colour it's the reverse of the one I wanted 107:105:248 !!

How can I get the correct &H hex value so that VBA will understand I want a red colour not purple !!

Comment: is there any reason you have to store it as a variable?

Comment: Yes, as there are two scales of colour to accommodate those with colourblindess.

Comment: refer to @Bathsheba 's answer. you can use `Band10Colour = rgb(248,105,107)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to use `VBA.RGB(...)` instead. The problem you're experiencing is down to the memory layout of `Long` clashing unexpectedly with the way the RGB structure is defined internally.

As `VBA.RGB(...)` returns a `Long`, just store the function output.